# Combine template and object class

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to know how can I combine the a template function to a class.
In order to the sorting of the classes. Here are the codes.

Template.h

```
template<typename T>
bool lessThan(T t1, T t2) {
bool result = false;
if (t1 < t2) {
    result = !result;
}
return result;
}

template<typename T>
bool greaterThan(T t1, T t2) {
bool result = false;
if (t1 > t2) {
    result = !result;
}
return result;
}
```

Point.h

```
//Operator Overloading
Point2D operator-(Point2D);
bool operator<(const Point2D& p2d)const;
bool operator>(const Point2D& p2d)const;
bool operator==(Point2D);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Please, just `return t1 < t2;` and `return t1 > t2;`.

Comment: I think you failed in both English grammar and writing code making sense.

Comment: why not use `std::less` and `std::greater`? for you have the comparison operators overridden.

Comment: If you plan to use 'lessThan' in Point2D::operator<, the call 't1 < t2' will come back to the Point2D::operator<.

Comment: @Chubsdad I dont want to use the operator<. Can i use just the less than

Comment: @Griwes: I don't quite appreciate the English grammar part of the comment. On the other hand, the comment is right in that the question does not make sense, what does the OP want to do? What has he tried? What is the issue? -- A usage example would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There's absolutely no need whatsoever for those free functions, and `operator==` should be const, and you don't provide `!=` or some other relational operators.